# Python filter rows in dataframe by date

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
month     count
2015/01   100
2015/02   200
2015/03   300
...
```

And want to get a new dataframe which contains month greater than a month, e.g.. 2015/03.

I tried to use the following code:

```
sdf = df.loc[datetime.strptime(df['month'], '%Y-%m')>=datetime.date(2015,9,1,0,0,0)]
```

I'm new to Python. Really appreciate it if some one can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rows which have months larger than `2015/02` for instance, use `pd.to_datetime` instead of `datetime.strptime` since the former is vectorized and can accept a Series object as parameter (assuming you are using pandas):

```
import pandas as pd
df[pd.to_datetime(df.month) >= pd.to_datetime("2015/02")]

#     month count
#1  2015/02   200
#2  2015/03   300
```